# Get data to export csv file using react-csv

Tags: reactjs

I am trying react-csv.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv

This is data:

```
users = [
{firtstname: 'Ahmed', lastname: 'Tomi' , email: 'ah@smthing.co.com'},
{firtstname: 'Raed', lastname: 'Labes' , email: 'rl@smthing.co.com'},
{firstname: 'Yezzi', lastname: 'Min l3b', email: 'ymin@cocococo.com'}
];
```

Data for react-csv:

```
<CSVLink data={this.props.users} >Download me</CSVLink>
```

Then, how do I get only lastname and email for csv.
I try to do like this but something went wrong.

```
handleExport = () => {
this.state.exportData = this.props.users.map((user, index) => (
user.lastname + user.email
));
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Two choices. Either map your data so it only contains what you need. Something like

```
<CSVLink data={this.props.users.map(x => ({ lastname: x.lastname, email: x.email }))}>Download me</CSVLink>
```

Or, use the headers prop to define the data you want

```
headers = [
  { label: 'Last Name', key: 'lastname' },
  { label: 'Email', key: 'email' }
];

<CSVLink data={this.props.users} headers={headers}>Download me</CSVLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<CSVLink data={this.state.exportData} >Download me</CSVLink>
```